# Where do independent digital wallets keep money?

Tags: banking, money-transfer, online-banking, electronic-payment

When you cash in to your independent digital wallet, where does the money go?

When I say "independent", I mean those digital wallets that are not backed by banks.

Comment: Can you give an example of an independent digital wallet? I don't know what you're talking about

Comment: @user253751 PayPal

Comment: paypal probably keeps its money in a bank

Comment: I’m quite, but not 100%, sure that they are keeping money in the bank since that is the place you transfer money to.

Answer (score 1):

You give Paypal as an example of this, so I'll use that.

The Paypal Balance Account [Terms and Conditions](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/ua/pp-balance-tnc) state:

> Any funds in your Balance Account represent **unsecured claims against**
> **PayPal**, unless you have a PayPal Debit Mastercard® (“PayPal Debit
> Card”), have enrolled in Direct Deposit, or have bought or received
> cryptocurrency. In that case, PayPal places the U.S. dollar funds held
> in your Balance Account in one or more Program Banks...

I am not a lawyer, but I take "unsecured claims" to mean they take your money as a sort of "loan". They use it how they want but you can always request it back.

So if you have a debit card, direct deposit, or crypto, then they deposit the cash in "pass-through" banks. This is exactly like the Paypal Savings account which uses Synchrony Bank as the pass-through. If you don't have these, the next paragraph says what they do with the money:

> If your Balance Account is not eligible for FDIC pass-through
> insurance, PayPal combines your Balance Account balance with the
> balances of other Balance Account holders and **invests those funds** in
> liquid investments in accordance with state money transmitter laws.

Read the T&C's for more details.

I would expect any other "digital wallets" with non-bank institutions do the same thing: either hold the cash in pass-through banks or invest it. You will have to look at the T&C's for that specific account to know for sure.